# How to solve this boundless problem?

Tags: analysis, mathematica

Try to make a function on $[0,1]$, which is unbounded in every neighborhood of every point.

Comment: Map rationals in lowest terms to their denominators.

Comment: @DavidMitra . Good one. Another one: Let $f:\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\to \Bbb N$ be a bijection.

Comment: Or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function.